# How to retrieve the exact Accessibility Tree or Accessibility Object Model (AOM) produced by Chrome with Playwright/Selenium?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, accessibility, playwright, uiaccessibility

Google Chrome (as far as I know, every other browser) analyzes the DOM and produces something called [Accessibility Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVhfw.png) (AT) where only the interactive and descriptive elements are shown (e.g. `<input>`, `<button>` etc. as interactive ones, `<span>`, `<label>` etc. as descriptive ones matched with the interactive ones). From the following implementation:

```
const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({ headless: false });
const context = await browser.newContext();
const page = await context.newPage();

const endpoint = "url";


await page.goto(endpoint);

await page.getByRole('textbox', { name: 'email' }).click()
```

I can conclude that the AT is also available to Playwright. What I need is to extract it [as it is in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVhfw.png).

Following implementation should retrieve the tree.

```
const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch({ headless: false });
const context = await browser.newContext();
const page = await context.newPage();

const endpoint = "url";


await page.goto(endpoint);

const snapshot = await page.accessibility.snapshot();
console.log(snapshot);
```

However, returned tree is not structured as it should have been (Parent-children information do not exists in it in anyway), it is just [a list of elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7R4fI.png) represented in some words. Are there any way in which resulting tree can be improved further?

Answer (score 0):

That accessibility feature is deprecated,

So you'd better use [@axe-core/playwright](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@axe-core/playwright) and see [Playwright accessibility
docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/accessibility-testing)